# Navigation View not working and covering full screen

Tags: android, android-studio, android-layout, android-fragments

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.project.noticeboard.mainNoticeBoard">

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <androidx.appcompat.widget.Toolbar
        android:id="@+id/toolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="?attr/actionBarSize"
        android:background="#03A9F4"
        android:elevation="5dp"
        android:theme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Dark.ActionBar"
        app:popupTheme="@style/ThemeOverlay.AppCompat.Light" />

    <FrameLayout
        android:id="@+id/fragment_container"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"/>

</LinearLayout>
<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/header_navbar"
    app:menu="@menu/navbar_main"
    android:layout_marginRight="200dp"/>


</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

I am trying to make navigation bar but it is covering whole screen and not responding to screen.
[this is the layout](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wO1t9.png)
I have fragment behind it, i suppose but by default navigation is open.

Answer (score 2):

I think, you are adding your fragments in "**fragment_container**" which is a FrameLayout inside LinearLayout instead of **nav_view**. I also observer you are using **match_parent** for **nav_view** height. Which will overlap your **fragment_container**. It's better to design your DrawerLayout like below code which is recommended by Android Developers.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:id="@+id/drawer_layout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    tools:openDrawer="start">

<include
    layout="@layout/app_bar_main"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent" />

<com.google.android.material.navigation.NavigationView
    android:id="@+id/nav_view"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_gravity="start"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    app:headerLayout="@layout/nav_header_main"
    app:menu="@menu/activity_main_drawer" />

</androidx.drawerlayout.widget.DrawerLayout>
```

Comment: not working still covering full screen if i do as you say

Comment: Can you push ur code and provide GitHub link if possible? I can look into it.

Comment: it worked i just removed the linear layout to check diffference and than added i again on same place and all of a sudden it worked not even one line change.

Answer (score 0):

Add `android:layout_gravity="start"` to your `NavigationView`. That will move it offscreen, until you swipe right to reveal it.